# Converting 1 BYTE to int value from 00..FF to 0..255

Tags: embedded, int, byte

Converting BYTE ( 00 - FF ) to int ( 0 - 255 ) value in MPLAB C
Ive tryed this but it doesnt work as i want it to:

```
 atoi(i)
```

and

```
(i - '0')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a hexadecimal number to base 10 efficiently in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-base-10-efficiently-in-c)

Comment: You cannot convert a **byte** from hex to decimal, because a byte is simply a number. It has a wide range of representations, and is not tied to any representation in particular. Are you looking for a *string representation* of your byte as a decimal number? Please be more specific.

Comment: i meant converting byte value, i see it like hexadecimal and what it like base 10.

Comment: Do you mean the ASCII representation of a byte? (BYTE, by the way, is not a standard type.) Or do you simply want to convert a byte to an `int`? If that is the case you can simply assign byte to an int. (Hexadecimal notation 0x0 - 0xFF represent the same *value* as the decimal notation 0 - 255.)

Comment: yes i simly want to convert a bytr to an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
unsigned char c = 0xF3; //there is no byte in C but unsigned char is basically equivalent
int i = c & 0xFFFF; //this will set i to the value of c;
```

output will be

```
i = 243; //the decimal version of 0xF3.
```

Comment: i = c & 0xFF; if you are talking about an 8 bit byte.  And that is if i = c; sign extends when you dont want it to.

Comment: @dwelch he said he wanted values between 0-255 so if you sign extend you might get a negative which wouldn't work. I did assume an 8 bit byte but he also as 0 - 0xFF so that's 8 bits.

Comment: right c&0xFFFF in your answer is 16 bits, not 8.  If it sign extends it would make it 0x0000 to 0xFFFF, not 0x00 to 0xFF.  And that is what I said about the sign extension but probably best to have the mask there anyway, the compiler will remove it if has the right instructions to avoid it.