# C operator "<<"

Tags: c, pseudocode

Was going through documentation (pseudocode) of a particular device.
At one point it had:

```
int b0 = charToInt(*something*)
int Data;
Data = (b0<<4);
```

What does `<<4` mean?

Comment: Google for `shift operator in c`

Comment: @EugenRieck - while it may be obvious to you that this is a shift operator, the OP may not have known that so wouldn't have been able to google for it.  Having said that, the first google hit I get for "<< operator c" is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: It does not look like pseudo code.  It looks like C.  :)

Comment: If you really want a laugh, extend @DigitalTrauma 's very good observation to some of the things I might have searched for when I first started (if Google had existed back then), i.e. "<<"   or "<< C" or "what is <<".  Half of the returned links were blocked by my companies firewall.  I certainly would not have thought to append the words _C operator_ to any of those searches  :)

Comment: My comment was meant to be **helpfull** not derogatory! I actually **ment** "You will get your answer if you google for 'shift operator in C'". English is not my first language, I apologize if I sounded rude. Again: I didn't mean to.

Comment: @EugenRieck - It was not taken derogatorily at all! Actually helpful.  I just had a little fun with it, and actually went out and tried some variations of search patterns that someone fairly new to C might type in, choosing what someone might ask, based on my personality as the standard.  Results were pretty hilarious.  I hope I did not offend you.

Answer (score 1):

That means to do a left shift 4 times on the binary representation of the number.

The number 4 = 0000 0100 in binary.

shifting the bit pattern left four times gives us 0100 0000

```
4 << 0 = 0000 0100 (what we start with)
4 << 1 = 0000 1000 (8)
4 << 2 = 0001 0000 (16)
4 << 3 = 0010 0000 (32)
4 << 4 = 0100 0000 (64)
```

0100 0000 = 64

Comment: i.e 2 to the power of 4

Comment: i.e. [multiply by 16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391801/c-operator/19391877#19391877)

Answer (score 1):

It is a left shift operator, and can be used in this way:
To generate powers of 2 use the following :

1 << 0 == 1
1 << 1 == 2
1 << 2 == 4
1 << 3 == 8
1 << 4 == 16

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

bit shift 4 places to the left, so if `b0` was 'A' it would be

```
'A' = 65 = 0100 0001
```

bit shifted to the left 4 times is

```
0100 0001 0000
```

Note: Ignoring bytes wapping you may or may not have

Answer (score 0):

<< is a bit operation, if I remember correctly. What it does is take the bit value of b0 and shift it over four places.
so if b0 = 00000101
b0 << 4 = 01010000

I don't use bitwise operators so I can't really tell you what they're useful for, but hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned, this does a bitshift 4 bits to the left.  Bit-shifting can be used to quickly multiply or divide by powers of 2.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_shift#Bit_shifts

- Each bitshift to the left effectively multiplies by 2 (watch for overflows, and signed integers).
- Each bitshift to the right effectively divides by 2.

So in this case you are doing:

- shifting 4 bits to the left, or
- multiplying by 2 four times, or
- multiplying by (2 to the power 4), or
- multiplying by 16.

Why would you want to multiply by 16 or <<4?  Well lots of reasons, but one possibility immediately springs to mind - converting a hexadecimal string representation of a number to the number itself.  [Convert a hexadecimal string to an integer efficiently in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-base-10-efficiently-in-c/11068850#11068850)

Answer (score -2):

The << operator is a bitwise shift. That particular one is a left shift.

Generally these are used in compression algorithms, practical usage in anything else doesn't really exist save very few explicit areas like image pixel setting.

Comment: hmm, how about multiply by 2-to-the-n?  (or divide by 2-to-the-n for >>).

Comment: The shift operators are immensely common and useful.

Comment: Should have stopped at:  _...is a left shift._.  Generally, I find that _generally_ is difficult to use on this forum :)