# Convert hex data from C to values

Tags: c, struct, hex

I have this structure :

```
UID (4 byte unsigned integer)
Message size (4 byte unsigned integer)
Date (4 byte time_t value)
```

In a file I have this data :

```
UID : 3C 05 00 00
Message size : 2F EA 02 00
Date : FA 11 02 53
```

I dont find how get each value in human reading ? Can you help me please ?

Normally the size is 8581o and the date 02-17-2014 14:39.

Comment: Start by reading about [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), then read more about the bitwise or and shift operators.

Comment: Perhaps your answer is already here .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-base-10-efficiently-in-c

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand I'm not a C developper... I just want to decode only this data for a check...

Comment: So why the tag `C`, then? You need someone to write you a decoder?

Comment: No just someone explain me how C store this data. Normaly FA110252 is 4195418706 in base 10. Date is a time_t so a timestamp if I understand. This value converted is not the good date 5/11/1966 20:36:50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned u = 0x530211FA;// little endian
    time_t t = (time_t)u;//sizeof(u) == sizeof(t) ?
    printf("%s\n", ctime(&t));//Mon Feb 17 22:43:22 2014
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was just little endian problèm !