# I don't know how to convert 16 byte hexadecimal to floating point

Tags: c

Probably from the time I am trying to convert and wandering internet solely for the answer of this question but I could not find. I just got I can convert hexadecimal to decimal either by some serious programming or manually through math. 
I am looking to convert. If there is any way to do that then please share. Well I have searched and found IEEE754 which seems not to be working or I am not comprehending it. Can I do it manually through any equation, I think I heard about it? Or a neat C program which may do it.

Please help! Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the hex value a string, constant ...

Comment: You have a string of 16 hex digits and you want to convert it to a number?  Why floating point?  Is it a fixed point value?  Your question is very unclear as written.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a hexadecimal number to base 10 efficiently in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-base-10-efficiently-in-c)

Comment: Let me clear my question, I don't want conversion of hexadecimal to decimal but rather to floating points. I am trying to convert my mac address to floating so that it could do some stuff that I want it do. Leave is there any type of equation to do it.

Comment: A FP MAC address? What could you do with such a repesentation that you could not do with an array of bytes, (that, I could understand).

Comment: There is something I want to do while don't want to declare so please if you have a method then share!

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the [IEEE floating point spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

This would be quite straightforward in Java. You have handy methods like `Float.floatToRawIntBits(float x)` and `Float.intBitsToFloat(int x)` 
You might be able to do it with a union.

In C its a bit more hacky. You can abuse a union. Unions in C reuse the same memory for two different variables. A union like

```
union DoubleLong {
  long l;
  double d;
} u;
```

would allow you to treat the same bit of memory as either a long `u.i` or a double `u.f`. There are both 8 byte so they take the same space. So doing `u.d = M_PI; printf("%lx\n", u.l);` prints the binary representation of pi 0x400921fb54442d18.

For 16 byte we need the union to have an array or two 8 byte longs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Data {
  long i[2];
  long double f;
} u;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  // Using random IP6 address 2602:306:cecd:7130:5421:a679:6d71:a660 
  // Store in two separate 8-byte longs
  u.i[0] = 0x2602306cecd7130;
  u.i[1] = 0x5421a6796d71a660;
  // Print out in hexidecimal
  printf("%.15La %lx %lx\n", u.f,u.i[0],u.i[1]);
  // print out in decimal
  printf("%.15Le %ld %ld\n", u.f,u.i[0],u.i[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

One problem is 16 byte hexadecimal floating point numbers might not be defined on you system. `float` is typically 32 bit - 4 byte, `double` is 64 bit - 8 byte. There is an `long double` type but on my mac its only 80-bit - 10 byte. It might be simpler to convert to two double precision numbers. So on my system only the last 4 hexadecimal digits of the second number are significant.

Not all hexadecimal numbers correspond to valid floating point numbers, a lot of values will correspond to NaN's. If the higher bits are 7FFF or FFFF (or 7FF, FFF for double) that will either give infinity of NaN.