# Improved method to obtain the size of an array

Tags: c

I have made a function that recieves a pointer of an array of characters, that represent an hexadecimal number, and returns the decimal value of it.

In that function, this is what I currently use to obtain the size of the array

```
size_t iSize = 0;
while (s[iSize] != '\0'){   iSize++;    }
```

I am looking to find a better method to do this. **I already tried int `iSize = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]).**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a hexadecimal string to an integer efficiently in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-efficiently-in-c)

Comment: To find the length of a null terminated string use `strlen`.  Based on your description that's what you care about, not the size of the array.

Comment: Have you thought about replacing your whole function that converts a hex string to a number with one function `strtol`?

Comment: size_t iSize = strlen(s); ?

Answer (score 0):

Size of array is not passed through a function. Example:

```
int my_getsize(int* ptr)
{
    return sizeof(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr)); //output: 400
    printf("%d\n", my_getsize(arr)); //output: 4
}
```

In a 32bit system `my_getsize(buf)` returns 4, which is the size of pointer. While `sizeof(buf)` returns 400 which is 100 * `sizeof(int)` (also 4). The only way to around this is to pass the array size to the function. For example `foo(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))`

Character arrays are a special case because the string is null-terminated, you can look for the last zero in the array. Note however this will not return the array size which includes the null-terminator. It's the same as `strlen`. Example:

```
size_t my_strlen(char* ptr)
{
    size_t iSize = 0;
    while (*ptr++) iSize++;
    return iSize;
}
```

For `char buf[] = "12345"`, `sizeof(buf)` is 6, while `strlen(buf)` is 5. Usually you need not worry about optimization with this sort of simple functions because the compiler does it for you.