# Issue converting char[16] to valid memory address (PVOID ?)

Tags: c

I am trying to read a value from a text file through kernel, which I do so via:
'ZwReadFile' and read into a
**CHAR streamRead[32]**

Printing this value shows

**Value is: 0000021A5DFFD9B0**
which is the correct string from the file, I then wish to pass this to a call of MmCopyVirtualMemory, which causes me problems and the functions fails because of this variable,
replacing it with the hardcoded **0x0000021A5DFFD9B0** works fine, can someone please point me in the right direction on how I can convert my value to a memory address?

The final form needs to be PVOID, but tried everything and can't get this to work properly, any help much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Presumably it's read in hexadecimal (ASCII characters between 0-9a-fA-F), so you need to convert back to bytes (combining two hex characters to make one raw byte). You'd also need to [reverse the byte order if the data was stored big endian and you're on a little endian system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3022552/364696).

Comment: You want to convert a string to a number, in hexadecimal. That's what to look for.

Comment: Can you use strtoull ? like this: https://onlinegdb.com/DwIsa6aQ1

Comment: Here is another question about converting strings of hex to integers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-efficiently-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long long hexstr_to_hexint(char hex[])
{
    long long decimal = 0, base = 1;
    int i = 0, length;
    length = strlen(hex);
    for (i = length--; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (hex[i] >= '0' && hex[i] <= '9')
        {
            decimal += (hex[i] - 48) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if (hex[i] >= 'A' && hex[i] <= 'F')
        {
            decimal += (hex[i] - 55) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if (hex[i] >= 'a' && hex[i] <= 'f')
        {
            decimal += (hex[i] - 87) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
    }

    return decimal;
}
```

Found some of this code elsewhere but can't remember where, edited to work properly however and removed clutter.